# Where to almost wild camp in the Ardennes?

Tags: safety, camping

Wild camping is not permitted in Belgium, but I heard about places where this is allowed. Well itś not exactly wild camping but almost.
Where are these places? are there any hiking trails associated?

I googled for it, but I only get traditional camping places.

Comment: This question fits better on [Outdoors.SE].

Answer (score 8):

In the Ardennes there are at present 14 places. Nine of them are in the Viroinval-Chimay region (south of the provinces Namur-Hainaut) and five are in the Parc Naturel des Deux Ourthes in the Luxembourg province.

A site that gives a very good overview of such places (for all of Belgium) is http://www.bivakzone.be (in Dutch). On this site you can also find information about hiking trails in the area.

If you google, the magic words are "aire de bivouac". That should give you all the information you want.